# Make virtualbox run faster on macOS?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, memory, macos-bigsur

I've been having trouble that my virtual machines on my MacBook run very slowly. I have a decent specifications. What steps should I take to improve performance?

For reference, I currently have given it access to two cores of my CPU and 8GB of ram. After that I insert Guest Additions. Whether running linux or windows I find it runs very slowly. Is this to be expected?

Comment: How many cores do you have (real/virtual) & how much RAM in total? What Mac are you running on?

Comment: MacBook Pro 2020, four core i5, 16GB total ram

Comment: A VM is always going to be slower, of course. I'd maybe give VMWare Fusion a try rather than VB. They do a 'free for private use' version now.